# How to filter firebase cloud storage with firebase cloud functions and send the data to the client

Tags: firebase, function, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

hello i am creating an app in flutter and using firebase cloud firestore to save data from the app.

The app uses a Calendar plugin to display appointments that the users have stored in cloud firestore, so i want to filter the appointment that the users can see by only showing the appointments of the current month and for that my idea is to use firebase cloud functions

is it possible for when the user opens the app, i could call a function in cloud functions that will filter the documents where the appointments dates is in the range of the current month and show it to the user?

or is there another way to solve this problem

Thanks in advance

Comment: Aside from the error... `return(populateOverlay);`..what is the purpose of this? Why are you returning the definition of the function from the execution of the function? Doesn't appear to make a lot of sense, on the face of it.

Comment: Anyway, the actual error can occur if the `<script>` block containing the function comes later in your page than the HTML containing the onlick attributes. Ensure the function is defined before it is used.

Comment: @the `return(populateOverlay);` was just my idea to solve the uncaught RefrenceError but i also saw it was not of any use, so i deleted it out, but i don't still I  understand how I can solve the problem

Comment: " i don't still I understand how I can solve the problem"...see my second comment

Comment: @ADyson that was really helpful, but i keep recieving the `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` when i click on a button, i have edited my question to understand the problem

Comment: `onclick="populateOverlay(LUKO,he does notihng,NONE)"` looks wrong. It should be `onclick="populateOverlay('LUKO','he does notihng','NONE')"`. Your single-quotes have gone missing. You didn't tell PHP to render any. So the JavaScript interpreter is getting confused between what is text and what is code.

Comment: `onclick="populateOverlay('.$name.','.$description.','.$facebook.')"` is the culprit.

Comment: `onclick="populateOverlay(\''.$name.'\',\''.$description.'\',\''.$facebook.'\')"` should fix it. Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c64e07a7b2c775256bbcbf46b72d6bf95f3e1045

Comment: @ADyson thanks for that i am sure that the bracket error is solved, but the `Uncaught ReferenceError: populateOverlay is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):119)` is back again.and i am sure the `<script>` block is called before the onclick attribute.

Comment: Is your JS code within the PHP file or in a separate JS file? It's a very simple error where the function doesn't seem to exist for the code that is trying to call it. As @ADyson said, it's either declared too late or is an external file and you don't have a link to it.

Comment: @PauloHgo the JS file is in an external file .this is how i linked it `public function worker_display()
 {
  ob_start();
  echo "<script src=\"$this->plugin_url/assets/display.min.js\"></script>";
  echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"$this->plugin_url/assets/display.min.css\" type=\"text/css\" media=\"all\" />";
  require_once( "$this->plugin_path/templates/display.php" );
  
  
  return ob_get_clean();
 } ` i have a php file to controll the metabox and all the actions of the plugin, and i added every link through a function. When i look in the console it seems to work.

Comment: This is confusing to me. Leave your JavaScript code separate from PHP. Include the JS code in a file like `methods.js` and refer to it in the header section of your PHP or HTML file, like `<script src="js/methods.js"></script>`, assuming that your JS file is in the `js` folder.

Comment: @PauloHgo really sorry for the dirty code. i have modified the question so you can see how the structure really is.

Comment: I don't see a reference to `display.js` anywhere in your code. There is a reference though to `display-min.js`. You either need to change your file name where you JS code is or change the reference to point to the correct file.

Comment: @PauloHgo my display.js is in a js folder and i am compresing this folder through **gulp** and converting it into a ( .min) . the   .min is sent to the asset folder and then read by the browser. i think the problem will be the reference as you said. and i thought that by referencing the   ` echo "<script src=\"$this->plugin_url/assets/display.min.js\"></script>"; ` i was pointing correctly to the folder but i was wrong. even tho i dont know how i can solve the reference problem yet,

Comment: @PauloHgo i finally understood it. i am really greatfull. the refrence should have been display.js, instead of .min.js

Comment: Glad I could help. Good luck.